# Turning a Cryptic Google Maps URL into Street View

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking down the barrel of some highly cryptic google maps URL sorcery (with a little embedded PHP to boot, but that's not altogether relevant):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?php echo $google_map_url ;?>&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=16&amp;sll=<?php echo $entity->long100,$entity->lat100 ;?>&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<?php echo $google_map_url ;?>&amp;ll=<?php echo $entity->long100,$entity->lat100 ;?>&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near
```

This works great for displaying a typical google maps view. But I want street view. My initial guess was to simply add `layer=c` to the querystring, but that has no effect. Since this is a bit of a wild goose chase to debug, I was wondering if any seasoned gmaps veterans could immediately spot my remedy.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to:

1. set the `output`-parameter to `svembed`
2. specify a `cbll`-parameter(the latlng for the streetview, may be the same as used for `ll` )
3. specify a `cbp`-parameter. This parameter is used to control the options of the streetview(like zoom, pich etc.) You don't need to specify these options, but you must set the parameter. The minimum-setup would be `cbp=,,,,`